# How does xgboost.cv use weights?

Tags: cross-validation, xgboost

I have set up a training data set (a DMatrix) for which I want to perform k-fold cross-validation.

```
train_data = xgb.DMatrix(data = X_Train, label = y_Train, weight = training_weights)
```

My question is: When i run a model using xgboost.cv(), will each fold have the same weight, or the same number of weighted observations?